# How to put image on day event? clndr.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone help me? 
I need to implement image on day event with clndr.js .

[image: here what i need to achieve]

When I have events on some day, I need to put this image with the amount of events of this day. 
I hope You will help.

This is my template when I have two events, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHBdY.png)

```
<script id="clndrTemplate" type="text/template">
          <div class="clndr-controls">
            <div class="clndr-previous-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
            <div class="clndr-next-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
            <div class="month"><%= month %> <%= year %></div>
          </div>
          <div class="clndr-grid">
            <div class="header-days">
              <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %>
              <div class="header-day"><%= day %></div>
              <% }); %>
              <div class="days clearfix">
                <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
                <div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>">
                  <span class="day-contents"><%= day.day %></span>
                  <% _.each(day.events, function(event){ %>
                  <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-images">
                      <span class="grey-img">
                      <img src="images/t-clndr.png" alt="">
                    </span>
                    <span class="white-img">
                      <img src="images/t-clndr-w.png" alt="">
                    </span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="amount-events">
                      <%  %>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <% }) %>
                </div>
                <% }); %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </script>
```

Comment: Could you please share the relevant code and what you have tried already? thanks.

Comment: Each day with clndr.js has his own class, so you could simply add content to that class with the use of :before or :after.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate a `<div>` on each day (using CSS) which will contain the number of events, you should set the id of this div to be the date of its day, something like "d29-09-16".
Then use jQuery:

```
 $("#d29-09-16").text(numOfEvents);
```

while numOfEvents is your counter of this day.